# Using Ajax.Updater to get a javascript file (prototypejs)

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

Here is my ajax request:

```
new Ajax.Updater({ success: 'footer' }, '/dyn/actions/checkSystemMessage', {
      insertion: 'after',
      evalScripts: true
    });
```

Here is what's at /dyn/actions/checkSystemMessage:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {

    buildSystemMsg = function(SystemMsg) {
        //behind container
        behindContainer = new Element('div', {id: 'behind-system-message'});
        behindContainer.setStyle({display: 'none'});
        document.body.appendChild(behindContainer);

        //main container
        container = new Element('div', {id: 'system-message'}).update(SystemMsg);
        container.setStyle({display: 'none'});
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        //hide button
        hideBtn = new Element('a', {'class': 'close-button', 'title': 'Close System Message'}).update('Close');
        hideBtn.setStyle({ marginTop: '5px'});
        container.insert({bottom: hideBtn});

        offsetY = container.getHeight();

        //show
        if ($('mod-system-alert'))
        { new Effect.Move($('mod-system-alert'), { queue: 'front', x: 0, y: offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 }); }
        new Effect.Move($('footer'), { queue: 'front', x: 0, y: offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });
        new Effect.Move($('page-container'), { queue: 'front', x: 0, y: offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });      
        new Effect.Move($('nav'), { queue: 'front', x: 0, y: offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });
        new Effect.Move($('header-container'), { queue: 'front', x: 0, y: offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });
        Effect.BlindDown(behindContainer, { queue: 'front', duration: 0 });
        Effect.BlindDown(container, { queue: 'end', duration: 0.5 });


        hideBtn.observe('click', function() {
            if ($('mod-system-alert'))
            { new Effect.Move($('mod-system-alert'), { queue: 'front', x: 0, y: -offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 }); }
            new Effect.Move($('footer'), { queue: 'end', x: 0, y: -offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });
            new Effect.Move($('page-container'), { queue: 'end', x: 0, y: -offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });       
            new Effect.Move($('nav'), { queue: 'end', x: 0, y: -offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });
            new Effect.Move($('header-container'), { queue: 'end', x: 0, y: -offsetY, mode: 'relative', duration: 0 });
            Effect.BlindUp(behindContainer, { queue: 'front', duration: 0 });
            Effect.BlindUp(container, { queue: 'front', duration: 0.5 });
            set_cookie("HideSystemMsg", true);          
        });
    }

    hideMsg = get_cookie("HideSystemMsg");
    systemMsg = '${SystemMsg}';
    if (systemMsg.length > 0 && !hideMsg)
        buildSystemMsg(systemMsg);

});

--></script>
```

This is neither inserting the javascript after the element with ID footer nor is it executing the script. It does rely on other javascript libraries that are included on the page where the update is occurring. Could this be where my problem is?

Comment: What is the MIME-Type of /dyn/actions/checkSystemMessage?

Comment: application/x-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe evalScripts will only work if your response headers have a "text/javascript" content type. This is what tells the AJAX library that what you're getting from the server is a script..

Additionally, you would not need the mark up: `<script type="text/javascript"><!--`, and: `--></script>`

I hope this helps.

Comment: The script markup is necessary due to our website architecture. The file it is getting has the extension .html.

Comment: Hi there,

If the markup is required, then I am not sure if it'll work by just appending it to the page. You may want to try turning evalScripts off as it expects Javascript headers and code in the response only.

If that doesn't work, then as a last resort I'd try using the DOM to actually get the Javscript code from within the comment block (<!-- -->) and then eval()'ing it.